Parsing Mail using MailParser node js don't work for attachment and image
I have an issue when I send an email with an attachment or image, an error that says that Embed size exceeds maximum size of 6000 and in the embed I can see a lot of letters and number like these
:/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB4RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAEABIBAwABAAAAAQAAADEBAgAH\r\n +
            AAAAPgAAABICAwACAAAAAQABAGmHBAABAAAARgAAAAAAAABHb29nbGUAAAMAAJAHAAQAAAAwMjIw\r\n +...  s

What I want is just to be able to process the content of the email such as image attachments etc... or otherwise just ignore them and keep the text such as the subject and subject of the email.
async function checkEmails() {
    const connection = await Imap.connect(imapConfig);
    await connection.openBox('INBOX');
    const searchCriteria = ['UNSEEN'];
    const fetchOptions = { bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'], markSeen: true };
    const messages = await connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions);

    for (const message of messages) {
        const subject = message.parts.filter(part => part.which === 'HEADER')[0].body.subject[0];
        const body = message.parts.filter(part => part.which === 'TEXT')[0].body;

        // Utilisation de MailParser pour extraire le contenu texte et les pièces jointes de manière asynchrone
        const parsedMail = await MailParser(body);

        // Construction du message Discord avec le contenu texte extrait
        const mailEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#05FF00')
            .setTitle('・Nouveau Message Sur La boite mail')
            .setDescription(`**__Sujet:__ \n${subject}\n\n __Corps Du message:__ \n${body}**`)
            .setFooter(client.config["serverConfig"].copyright + ` | Fait par Blacky`, 
                       client.config["serverConfig"].server_icon);

        // Gestion des pièces jointes
        if (parsedMail.attachments.length > 0) {
            for (const attachment of parsedMail.attachments) {
                const attachmentBuffer = Buffer.from(attachment.content, 'base64');
                const attachmentAttachment = new MessageAttachment(attachmentBuffer, attachment.filename);
                mailEmbed.attachFiles([attachmentAttachment]);
                mailEmbed.addField('Pièce jointe', attachment.filename);
            }
        }

        // Envoi du message Discord
        client.channels.cache.get('1239521836598034506').send({ embeds: [mailEmbed] });
    }

    // Planification de la prochaine vérification des e-mails dans 1 minute
    setTimeout(checkEmails, 60000);
}

I expect the code to send an embed in Discord with information like the object the subject attachment if there are etc...
The error I get:
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embeds: Embed size exceeds maximum size of 6000
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Promenade_chien_bot\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Promenade_chien_bot\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Promenade_chien_bot\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:158:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/1239521836598034506/messages',
  code: 50035,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [
        {
          title: '・Nouveau Message Sur La boite mail',
          type: 'rich',
          description: '**__Sujet:__ \n' +
            'dzdzd\n' +
            '\n' +
            ' __Corps Du message:__ \n' +
            '--000000000000ee9b3b0618573626\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000ee9b3b0618573625"\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            '--000000000000ee9b3b0618573625\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            'qzdqdqdqdzqzdqzd[image: image0 (6).png]\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            '--000000000000ee9b3b0618573625\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            '<div dir="ltr">qzdqdqdqdzqzdqzd<img src="cid:ii_lw55n33g0" alt="image0 (6).png" width="450" height="253"><br></div>\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            '--000000000000ee9b3b0618573625--\r\n' +
            '--000000000000ee9b3b0618573626\r\n' +
            'Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="image0 (6).png"\r\n' +
            'Content-Disposition: inline; filename="image0 (6).png"\r\n' +
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
            'Content-ID: <ii_lw55n33g0>\r\n' +
            'X-Attachment-Id: ii_lw55n33g0\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QB4RXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAEABIBAwABAAAAAQAAADEBAgAH\r\n' +
            'AAAAPgAAABICAwACAAAAAQABAGmHBAABAAAARgAAAAAAAABHb29nbGUAAAMAAJAHAAQAAAAwMjIw\r\n' +
            'AqAEAAEAAADCAQAAA6AEAAEAAAD9AAAAAAAAAP/bAIQACQYHEhISFRcXFxcXFxcVFRUVFxcXIRcW\r\n' +
            'FRcVHR4VGR4eHSAlJRklHx0lFR4lJiEeIi8tJS0oJS0uMCU1KScyIQEKCgoPExUQExUTLRkfHy0t\r\n' +
            'MTUtLTEvNS01NSU3Ly81Mi4tLS0tLTEwNi01NjIvNjctMSY1LTUlLTExLiYvMCU5/8AAEQgA/QHC\r\n' +
            'AwERAAIRAQMRAf/EABsAAQABBQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAQIDBQYH/8QAORAAAgEDAgUCBQIEBQQD\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAECAwQRBSEGEjFBUWFxEyKBkaEywUKx0eEVUmLw8RRDotIWIzP/xAAaAQEAAgMBAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAQIDBAUG/8QAMhEBAAICAQQBAwEGBgMBAAAAAAECAxEEBRIhMUETUfCRFCJhcYGhMkKx\r\n' +
            'weHxFVLRU//aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A9xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKZAZAZCTIDIQqgAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0JAGQKZCdGQjSuQAFQgyBUAAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALQlQJUbIFvMFtKcwNHMDSqkDS5MlXSq\r\n' +
            'ZAqSgAqEGQKgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUYFAlY2QtpjciFo\r\n' +
            'hjlUC8VYnXK7Xii6NUlHauVQI7V6qEqzVephWYXqRKulUwjSuSUKgVTAqEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACmQGQKBKjYFjkQvEMcpELRDBOoV2yRVGr1iJlmpRyOv646Ne33\r\n' +
            '+VucZezSS/JrZMupq7fD4UZMeb7xrToba8yZot6czJh0lxrFtsE0ZY1i21JoyxqhSassZltqTVkU\r\n' +
            'wrpepEqzC5MK6XZJQAVyEKgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABTIFAkyBbkJ0o5\r\n' +
            'EJ0scyFohinMheKsFSqRtlrVGqVisyzVogXdfYpaWzjo8342m5Th6c37HN5NvMPW9IjVb/0/3dDw\r\n' +
            '3qLnTi31xh+6NjDk3EOVzuN22tDoqdybMWcqcTPC4LRLHONIhXJiWKaM8a5bbFNFal4optvZf8Du\r\n' +
            'RGGZmISqdXJaJYbUZ4zJY5hepEqzC9MlXSoQAXBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AtYSAWtkJ0scgtpY5kLaWOoQtFWKVUja8VYKlYjbLFESrXKzLNWiHVrlJlsVxtbeXJivZuYsbmZW\r\n' +
            '/wAe6px/1L+r/BxOZm06s5JxYclkqvSVvc1YL9LfNH0ys4/I4OfuiGHFacuHHaffn/VsKN8dmLsF\r\n' +
            'sCTTvS3ewThS6N2WizDbEzu7L9zF9Fppaj8e6jTX6KXzz9ZP9C+nUxd+7a+zd/Z4pim8x5t6/p7d\r\n' +
            'bb1jZiXFvRMhULbYJqzQmW2xzVljIKTC9MlXS5MlVUC4IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAUYFrCVrkQtEMcpELxDDOoRteKsM6pG2SKsE6xG2SKI9S4K7Zq40WpclZlmjGiVbkpNmeuNBr\r\n' +
            'XRSbNimJqLy8xlmrmyab+LE2fBth1ry/hzj3/seX5eXe2j1XkesVfz1LU6vbVJ1JTUW223tuZuNm\r\n' +
            'iG/xcmOlK0mdNHK9qxljCXudaOR48OnGHHMbiXR2+nXfJzfDTT6OMk/5M1bdRrvX5/o49+Txt67/\r\n' +
            'AO0mnucY4lnmTec7Pfc3ePytpzdtp3X0s1PVPhwk/C29X2N6cmvK2Di91ohg4Ni1BzfWpLmf0yiM\r\n' +
            'PiNr9U/xdsequ1t6xtxPw4F6JtKsX21rUSadUtEsNqJMKhO2Kas0ZlmOYZUyVJheiVVUEKgAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABRgUbCVjZC0QxSkQvEI9SoVZa1RKtwVmWeuNDqXZSbNiuJGnd\r\n' +
            'Fe5ljEh3F2VmzYpiaGGuJycJbSTx6P1Rr/WdL9imIi0R4lWrfk/UTXA1y1PnT92vsyk5G1+zalFh\r\n' +
            'N1JJLoczlZmaY7Iel6ZbqlbJS22y/qzzeWZnbx+fJ9TLMwlToU6lJwWMNdiKzqdsEXvW0Wn28y1v\r\n' +
            'TJUqjTXT8o7GDLuPb2XD5UXruJb3g7VfhPkl+l/hmryabczqvE7v3o9/9N3xRZybjOKztiWN3jsY\r\n' +
            'uNlmsub0/NWO6tpefcS21RcqlFxTbxnbL27eh3MeeL+Ieq6fmxz3TE7mG30uSjFJdlg6uOWjnruZ\r\n' +
            'lu6N0Zos51sSZSvEX7mC2FLpXiL9zBbDKbRuS0Wa98adSqF4lrWqkwkWYZhlTJUmF5KqqCFQAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACjAoErJMhaIYpyIXiEapUKzLNWqFXqlZlsUo5vW9UqU/005T9U\r\n' +
            '0l/X8Gve8x8bdXi8alvd9f0aGy1qvWlyxhFPxKai/wA4OZm5nb7jTpZuJhxxEzf+0txitH/9Kbj6\r\n' +
            'pqS/BrY+pVn8/wCGj3YpnVL7YLpvBuU5O2bHppqdlSq14qo+VSTjzeJfwv8AY0+VkmI3VvZM2THj\r\n' +
            'tNPcIfEGmVLSpyOWU1mL8r2MfHz90bhscDlUz1m3bqYQNKtJTlyru/uWy5tQ2+TmrWNz8PQdF4c+\r\n' +
            'BNSmlhLPnfscXPydvKcvqP1azWvuTiLV5S2SxH+ZTDSJODxKxuZ8yj6FeVFLmSb2w/G/TJbNWIZu\r\n' +
            'bhpMREzpt6mjf9Q3Ko8ZW2DDTNMenPjmfSjto5jU9OlbVdt8Ya22fjY3qZIs7XH5Nc9PPhW04kqU\r\n' +
            'nJ45pS6uT2+3QmePEoy9MpftiJ1ENDrWoVLifPJ5eyXZJI3cNOyPDp8PjUxV7awl29Ro6dc0QxZK\r\n' +
            'wkSv1Hv9hPKj7sUYJn1CDX4hcekX98Exyfs2KdP7vc6WW3EVxUlywgs+r6GSua0+oMvTsVI3a/8A\r\n' +
            'Z1miwrvDqVc/6YxSX36m1Tu+ZcPlTi9Upr+O3VW9U2YlxslU+lMs1rVSISLMUwzRZLHMLkyULggA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWhK1shMMU5ESyRCLVqFZZq1Qq1UpMtilGuuK5SZbdKNPeV0\r\n' +
            'YbS38VJaW45ZPDWf2NDkViXQp3R5h1nCNVuEot5S6Z32PK8j24PU6RFotEe0rUNEjJPk+V+Oz/oM\r\n' +
            'WeasWDm2rru8vOeIbedKpiSx+UdfFk74et4GWl67hp7/AFGdWXNNtvp9F0NimKKxqG/g41McarGo\r\n' +
            'dFwPcwhWi5bLffw2ng0uZXw5PWMd7Y7RX89PTqNeFRPDyujOLp461LU9+HMcZVYLkisbZbx2zg2s\r\n' +
            'FZ8ux0mlp77fy/3TdFuqdC1hJ/xN+7ef2K5K2m0tfl475M1oiPX/AMZ4cR0XnqvHqVnHZinp+aPg\r\n' +
            'tKMbjmlNZTxj09jHXcSnJe2Ltis6mGh4r0SnTUZQ2TymvY3MGWfl0+mc29pmLMPC1hbzzGUeao88\r\n' +
            'ra+Vbe5fPltHpbqWbPHmJ1WP5NlT4QWd2jX/AGmzVt1efiPz9EqpottbwcpQ532z3+nQiM15n214\r\n' +
            '5efLbti2nnfEtZTntCMEuiisfd9zs8aZ17es6bimkebd21eHqXKsvq3k62H0nm27p8fDsrKsjbrL\r\n' +
            'gZaS29vWMsS0L0bKhVMm2peiZSqFolr2qkwkWYphljIlSYXZJVVyACFQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAowla2EwxTZC8Qj1ZlGWsINeqVmWzSrW3NYxzLbx0aLUb5RT3MN7Olgw7cjf8Qb4jv69Eat\r\n' +
            'srvYenz8+EG3vak5dTUy5J02b4KVj09T4OUFS78z65/Y81yLR3PE9T75v59OhMLluJ4i0BybaTZs\r\n' +
            'cbk9viXoeBz4rHmXG3+iTpveLXvsdfHyYl6HBzq39TtM4e06U6kYru/sYeRljTX5/JitZs7C/t6t\r\n' +
            'umouXLtutsnMrMTLz+G+LNMTaPLhdTvJc2518OONPTcfDXXhgq6tUlCEe0E0vq8syxgruf4steHS\r\n' +
            'LXt99f2Y6V7LItihe2CPs7TTeLVToxgo/Ms5b6bvPQ5uTizMzLznI6Ta+S1pnUfn8UfVOLpVIcrj\r\n' +
            'Bp+UXx8XU7ZOP0ftmLd35+q7gy5Xxo59f5MpyqaT1bHMUt+fZ6E2cy9tajW3lYYbylzwax1RHfP2\r\n' +
            'ZMdu2YmHJXXCM55ey9zfxcqYjy7dOrxXxr8/Rz91p1Wi8Y6HSw878/IdXFyceSPbLZXm+Hs/B1cP\r\n' +
            'JiVMuH5b60uTepfbm5cTb29czRLRvRsKNYyRLUvRNp1CzXtVnjMsxzDLGRKkwvTJV0qEKphCoAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtYSxyZC0MFSRDLWEOtMpLYpVrbmqY5lt46tNfXWDFazoYcTieJa7ks\r\n' +
            'J4Wd15NPLMvQ8DH2z6c7GJrOvMul4VsqdSaU5OGejxlZ8M0OVeYhxup58lK7rXf5D1XTtOjRWE8+\r\n' +
            'pwbRudy8Tn5Fsk7lNDAAazWZQcHGUHJP6Y9vUjFmjfht8at4tuttOf0CEKM3KWe6isZ6+ptZcm3T\r\n' +
            '5s3yRFY8ujoarSm+V7N7YfcwRE/DlX4uSsb14eW61CMq0lHpzPH32O3hnUPZ8K01x1m3ttLPguu5\r\n' +
            'JSjyrbMsprH9TDfmV+Gnl61i1us7n7ef/i98KOVVwp7pP9T29ykczwrHVdUi1/E/n8Gr1nS/gzcY\r\n' +
            'tyxs30TffC9DPizRaNt3h8v6lYtMa38LNN0epVliKbZOTPFVuRzaY43M6dDp+g1ab/S00aGbkRLl\r\n' +
            'Z+fiv8u1s3Uwuf8AucvJafE6eeydnntTDPEsCyrPlWfBW0zEJrG5YYyp1V0T9GTWy8xan8Gm1fhm\r\n' +
            'nNNwXLJbpdmbOPkWrLocXqV6zq07hzltUayn1Twz0vE5HdDr3rE+Y9Nva3B1K2aWTG2dCuZYlpXo\r\n' +
            '2FGsXiWraiXTqF4lgtVJhMlimGWMizHML0wquJQqghUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABRgWyC0MU2V\r\n' +
            'XiEWrIrLNWEC4kUls44aXULjBivLo4MbhNb1p8zjHr3fg0suV6Th8ONbsh2Gmzry7ybOXm5GvbYz\r\n' +
            '8mmKPtDePg2slnkf+/qacc6HNjrWL/2/P0QIW0qM91jBebxaG3OWMlfHl6Rw3qHxaeH1X5RyMldS\r\n' +
            '8fzuP2W/m3BRpAFs6afVFZrVMTLC7Gn/AJUWiF/rX+7leJ9LcFzR6fyZs8e3l2un8qLT229uIjRk\r\n' +
            '546s6szGnpZvWK7l3HDFWrHCbbj0aZyeVePbzPUKY53aI1Lq6FtGHRGtpxb5LW9tLr2iKaco9erR\r\n' +
            'mx5Jh0OFzZr+7KHpmtThiLinjbPRv3LZKx7hnz8Gs7tFnUUKikk13NeJce1e2ZiWQlVjqz5VnsYp\r\n' +
            'jt9elq134cnxPxJFLlh9X+x0MHH7nb6f060z3Wanh/Xmpr8mXPxtQ3+dwImr0OlUUkmujOft5S1Z\r\n' +
            'idacjxBatVXLGM9fDfk6HB5HbPn89u7wMn7mt70g0W0emxZ4ltX1LY0KxtVu1b0bK3rmWJad6NhR\r\n' +
            'qmSJhq2qmUpl4a9qpMJFmGYZoslSV6JUXICoQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWsJWyIlMMM2QyQiVW\r\n' +
            'Vlnq1tzIxy28cOS4jrvklh4eOvg1sku5waRuNvO6HXc5l3rb+IeqcBulGnnK55Pp3SX9TgcuZ35e\r\n' +
            'G6x9Sb+vEf76deaXhxHIcbWWWpJdVh/Q2uPk1LudIzTG6zP55a3hO7dOos9Oj+pk5NfG251PFFq7\r\n' +
            'h6CjR28uAACAj31v8SEo+V+SdsmK/baLOL0u3jTuYt9n/Y2rZJmr0PJyWtitEO5+FHOcLJpTWJ9v\r\n' +
            'N90/deWQAcnUp0o15Rnsm9pL+H+xlruYdqtsk44tX9HT21NRiknlefJhiNORe0zMyykqMV1T5oSX\r\n' +
            'lDS1J1MS8g4ii1Jnc4mtQ97wJjUHDNvKdSMV1b2LcqfEnUcla0m0/D1yyt3Tgl1OBEedvCZr90zO\r\n' +
            'l9xQjNYksonaKXtWd1ny09TQP8ktvDX7m1i5Vqt6vPn/ADV21OpUnR/UseGt0zr8bqG/f5/Zvce8\r\n' +
            'ZPXlFttUjnZo7OPPEs9+NP2buzvUzbraHOy4ZhuLepkyw0L1Tqci8Ne0JEGSwyyolSVxKFUEKgAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAWhKxkLQw1CGSqFcSwUlsUhoNUu1FPwYb2/o6fHxb0814h1n4jcYvbu/Jz\r\n' +
            '8mTfp6/g8Pt1azRwlg15h05hv9E1NwaNHkYIs5fM4sWh6lpevUasVmSUu6f9Ti3w2iXiORwslJnx\r\n' +
            '4Za7p3CcPG6ZiiZiVKd+KYs11rw84SzsWyZLTGm5k6hFob9y5V7GK1prHpzIjctVe8QU4bJZZmpS\r\n' +
            'Z9Q3MXAvb+TW/wDyGcun4WS04Z+7c/8AH0r7S7LXG3825jtSYYMvBj/K3tKqpLKIidubaup1Lz7i\r\n' +
            'S9jGvLl6Z/Pc38GLcPU9PwzOOu3RcM638VKL3fZmtmxzWXK5/C+nM2h0RhcpRvAHmfEeqJ1pNPbO\r\n' +
            'x0+Pg8PYdP4s/TrEt/wdq6l8rfXoavIwds7crqvEmurRH54dcaziLZTS6sbhMRt57xppMoycsfK9\r\n' +
            '0/Hozo8PJ8fL1HSOXExFd+f+2j0KvOlUUo7NdO/obWfUxqXU5mOuSs1n07alxFVxuk/ocqcbzdum\r\n' +
            '134lAr69KUlzZx4ReOPEtmnT61rPb7dJpVzSkvknn0ezNa2KYlyORjyVn96qXqFlGtDlf38Fq215\r\n' +
            'YcOaaWi0PMeKdG+A888H6J/N9js8TLNnsOm876v7va1mja9OlNKUsw9eqOziyzHuW9y+BW1Zmsal\r\n' +
            '6Vpd8pJHRpZ5DkYdN7QqmaJc69U2ky8Na0M6JY5XkqqoIVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAtCVjIWhi\r\n' +
            'mQvCBdx2KS2ccvN+ItBu6snmrFx7LHKv3/LNHLivPy9Xwefx8cRrH5++2jjwnV7tfTcwfQn5l1P/\r\n' +
            'AC1Piv5+iVR4ajHrmXuW+jDDbqVp9eEhaeodFgTjYvrzPtgrZXTY0s3GiWWup9t5wtrkqcsSWU+v\r\n' +
            'n6HF5WCI8w5nUeDFo3E6076jVUkmu5zItE+HmbVmPCtWGU0Jj+CKzry4PifS50/mbWG8Lfc6HGtH\r\n' +
            'rT0vTuXW89ul2ha/8KKgqa/1PO8n5Jz49+dq8zp/fabTk/s6WVjTrxU4rlb/AN7mlMz6ciM18czS\r\n' +
            'fMNfffGtqUnlYeF/dF8UbnTaxfSzXrGnnl25TkdrHqIesxarDb6JGpTaluvBq8i0S0OZNL7h3UNe\r\n' +
            'j8PLXzLt5Ob2z6eZtwbd2vhyWu63Ulnd+3Y3OPgj5d3h8GlfhxV3Vk2djHWIh6TFSIhO0a4kmsGD\r\n' +
            'kUiYavLx1mJem6Nd16kPOO7OBljU+HjeViw0syXNjVl/yY6+JVx58cNZqVK6UHHMuXv3NrFeu/MN\r\n' +
            'vj243dE68/1azQE6U8OKlFvdNJ/Z9TPmyRMNznRGSu4nUu4lYUpL9K+iwaW3m4zXj1LUalw1GW8O\r\n' +
            'vhmSuWYdDB1K1fFnL6lY1rdOTi1Fd+xuY5rbw7PH5GHLPbFvLTVNeqPbmf3NyvFj7OhXp9I86WOx\r\n' +
            'lVWc4fsb+PjLxnrT4YocL1ZP9SNmME/daeqVj/L+fo6TRuGJ0+lepH0ilj7PJs48Mx/mcbl9Qpf3\r\n' +
            'jj9XVWWl1V/36j91D/1NmtZ+7iZc9P8A84/u6CzpyS3k5erSX8sGaIc7JMT6jSZEswSvJVVQQqAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABaErWiEwxyRC8I1WBDLWUCvbJlJhtUyS19a0RjmrarllBr25SYbNMjWXN\r\n' +
            'IxzDdx2aO+aWWa2WdQ6GGJ8Qn8N6LVq/Ol8uerePsed5eePTV5/Nx0/cmfL0KhHkgs7YW5yoeVvM\r\n' +
            '2t48sE9XopZcl7dy8Vt8MscXJM67XPX03dzSj07Lx5ZlrM1dTDWOPWZtKXbcKqPWW/oiLZplhv1S\r\n' +
            '0/H5+jY0rWVHo8o1L2mGpbLXJ7jygcW1828c7OT6ext8fzO2z03HP1f5Od4Y0uNWrv0W7+htZ8uo\r\n' +
            '063UeVNK6j272rZwkknFYXT09jQ37eYrltE7iUN6VTT6ZT6p9vqVm0wz/tV/vqUa84ZpT6Zj+UZ6\r\n' +
            '5bQzYupZa+524rX+GpUnnG3ZrodDBy9vRcHqdbsnCOj06k2pS5WsNLH6uufsOTlnSvVOZekRNa7j\r\n' +
            '/p6RbW8acVGPRHJ9vI5Mk2ncsoVANXqGmxfzRWGuvqJ228HImP3Z9K2GqU2lFvDW2/cmInSM3GvG\r\n' +
            '5iPDYTnhN+hGmtEedPMeKeIJ1U4OXy5zhI6/Ewa8vY9O6fSkxbXlxqqLmy1leDrV8PRds6+zttBl\r\n' +
            'GcU10/kb2PTznM3WZiXT2tujZiIcbJkba2omSIaN7NhRgZIhq2lLposwSzJEqSuJVVQQqAAAAAAA\r\n' +
            'AAAAAAAAAAAAAABRhK1gWtELRLDOJEskSj1IFWWsodamVmGxWzX3FIxzDapZpdR2Ris6GDy4TVr7\r\n' +
            'mqYXRfzOdn8+HpeLg1Xf3dDpfGFSnTjBcqUVhbHHy8TcuRyOjUtabb9/n3XalxbUqrGyXp+5WnDO\r\n' +
            'N0imOdz5/P5tLC9nOXUz2xRV0ZwUrHp6DwhQlFNtde5x+RfcvK9TyRM636/4dKYpclRoSOH4xqyl\r\n' +
            'Ua7R2S/35N3jah6PpVKxWJ+Z/wCUrgqDTfqjFybRtg6tO9fn2deYHCa3V'... 3929 more characters,
          url: null,
          timestamp: 0,
          color: 392960,
          fields: [],
          thumbnail: null,
          image: null,
          author: null,
          footer: {
            text: "© 2024 Doogie Dogs's | Fait par Blacky",
            icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1238922548683604081/1238985951611453690/Doogie.png?ex=66414716&is=663ff596&hm=0511dc5710ca65a06d032125efc140b0236735e9780171e58e0c451cb7b5ae1c&'
          }
        }
      ],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined,
      thread_name: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}

